# logs index missing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Query DSL(Domain Specific Language) to write a query to retrieve documents containing error messages, which are in the indices "logs". But whenever the query is executed there are no hits. When i listed the set of indices, using the Kibana UI, there is no index named "logs". How is the logs index created? Should it be created separately or is it by default created? Basically, what are logs?

I am not very familiar with Elasticsearch. I have just went through a few tutorials online, but am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

1.Get all the indices in your es cluster, confirm you have indices named 'logs'

```
curl -XGET "http://172.31.4.253:19201/_cat/indices"
```

2.If the indices exists in your cluster but can't find in kibana, you just need to add an `Index Pattern`, go kibana -> Management -> Index Patterns, add your index pattern there.

FYI:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html